# Possible to display multiple html results from different divs in one or multiple Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Wondering if it's possible to get multiple divs refreshed with the data pulled from one or more Ajax calls, called by the same button.

I'm getting the correct results, just having a difficult time showing more than one div being refreshed with the html result.

I've tried the following ways;

```
$(document).on('click', '#customButton', function(event) {

var rangeDate_from = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_from")[0].value;
var rangeDate_to = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_to")[0].value;

  $.ajax({
       url: "load1.php",
       data: {'action' : 'search_prods', 'rangeDate_from' : rangeDate_from, 'rangeDate_to' : rangeDate_to},
       type: 'post',
       success: function(result) {
          form_updated = true;
          $('#dd_stocktake_details').html(result);
         },
           error: function() {}
         });

});

$(document).on('click', '#customButton', function(event) {

var rangeDate_from = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_from")[0].value;
var rangeDate_to = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_to")[0].value;

  $.ajax({
       url: "load2.php",
       data: {'action' : 'search_prods', 'rangeDate_from' : rangeDate_from, 'rangeDate_to' : rangeDate_to},
       type: 'post',
       success: function(result2) {
          form_updated = true;
          $('#dd_stocktake_details_2').html(result2);
         },
           error: function() {}
         });

});
```

And

```
$(document).on('click', '#customButton', function(event) {

var rangeDate_from = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_from")[0].value;
var rangeDate_to = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_to")[0].value;

  $.ajax({
       url: "load1.php",
       data: {'action' : 'search_prods', 'rangeDate_from' : rangeDate_from, 'rangeDate_to' : rangeDate_to},
       type: 'post',
       success: function(result) {
          form_updated = true;
          $('#dd_stocktake_details').html(result);
         },
           error: function() {}
         });

         $.ajax({
              url: "load2.php",
              data: {'action' : 'search_prods', 'rangeDate_from' : rangeDate_from, 'rangeDate_to' : rangeDate_to},
              type: 'post',
              success: function(result2) {
                 form_updated = true;
                 $('#dd_stocktake_details_2').html(result2);
                 alert(result2);
                },
                  error: function() {}
                });

});
```

Both these ways get me the results I want correctly, but both of these options only seem to display the first div each time.

If any more code needs to be seen, just ask!

Any ideas?

Comment: Change .html(resultx) to .append(resultx)

Comment: Hey Mplungjan, thanks for that - doing this does bring back the results although it doesn't remove the previous results. So I end up having two tables, one with the old data and one with the new queried data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery When
ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
        $(document).on('click', '#customButton', function (event) {

            var result1;
            var result2;
            var rangeDate_from = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_from")[0].value;
            var rangeDate_to = document.getElementsByName("rangeDate_to")[0].value;
            $.when(
                $.ajax({
                    url: "load1.php",
                    data: { 'action': 'search_prods', 'rangeDate_from': rangeDate_from, 'rangeDate_to': rangeDate_to },
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (result) {
                        form_updated = true;
                        result1 = result;
                    },
                    error: function () { }
                });

            $.ajax({
                url: "load2.php",
                data: { 'action': 'search_prods', 'rangeDate_from': rangeDate_from, 'rangeDate_to': rangeDate_to },
                type: 'post',
                success: function (result) {
                    form_updated = true;
                    result2 = result2
                },
                error: function () { }
            });

            ).then(function () {
                $('#dd_stocktake_details').html(result1);
                $('#dd_stocktake_details_2').html(result2);
            });

        });
```

Comment: This is not how `$.when()` works. Also, this code will throw a syntax error.